# Python: Pandas Dataframe, groupby but keeping otherwise missing values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My dataframe is looking something like this:

```
       date    |  status  |  value
0      2020-01 |  true    |  3
1      2020-01 |  true    |  8
2      2020-02 |  true    |  5
3      2020-01 |  false   |  1
4      2020-01 |  false   |  11
```

For most functions I would call `groupby`...

```
df_group = df.groupby(['date', 'status'])[['value']].agg('sum').reset_index()
```

...and obtain this:

```
       date    |  status  |  value
0      2020-01 |  true    |  11
1      2020-02 |  true    |  5
2      2020-01 |  false   |  12
```

But what I'm trying to reach is a dataframe, where also the 'missing' values are listed, like this:

```
       date    |  status  |  value
0      2020-01 |  true    |  11
1      2020-02 |  true    |  5
2      2020-01 |  false   |  12
3      2020-02 |  false   |  0
```

Is `groupby` even the correct funtion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), also remove `[[]]` and instead `agg` is possible use only `sum`:

```
df_group = (df.groupby(['date', 'status'])['value']
              .sum()
              .unstack(fill_value=0)
              .stack()
              .reset_index(name='value'))
print (df_group)
      date  status  value
0  2020-01   False     12
1  2020-01    True     11
2  2020-02   False      0
3  2020-02    True      5
```